# VS Code theme not being applied to integrated terminal VS Code

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code

I've just got a new Mac, and I can't seem to get the theme to apply to VS Code's integrated terminal.

I've come from Windows, where simply applying the theme (Material by Mattia Astorino) works fine.

Am I missing something?

(I'm new to OSX, so more than likely operator error)

[image]